# Mikrotik IPSec VPN routing

Tags: router, vpn, ipsec, mikrotik

I seem to be clueless at the routing with VPN. I am trying to setup an IPSec VPN tunnel so as to secure communication between my private LAN and a destination host. Any device within my private LAN should be able to initiate connection to the destination host. However, if the destination host wants to connect to my network (directed to my public IP address), I want to forward that connection to just one particular server - 192.168.1.65.

My setup:
Private LAN : 192.168.1.1/24
Public IP : 50.X.X.X

Destination Host IP : 173.X.X.X (using CISCO ASA)

I got the basic setup working fine and my internal LAN is able to access the internet. My attempt at the IPSec configuration is as follows:

```
/interface ipip
add comment="" disabled=no local-address=50.X.X.X mtu=1460 name=ipip1 \
    remote-address=173.X.X.X
/ip address
add address=192.168.1.1/24 broadcast=192.168.1.255 comment="" disabled=no \
    interface=ipip1 network=192.168.1.0
/ip ipsec peer
add address=173.X.X.X/32 auth-method=pre-shared-key comment="" \
    dh-group=modp1024 disabled=no dpd-interval=disable-dpd \
    enc-algorithm=3des exchange-mode=main generate-policy=no \
    hash-algorithm=md5 lifebytes=0 lifetime=1d nat-traversal=no port=500 \
    proposal-check=obey secret=SECRETKEY send-initial-contact=yes
/ip ipsec policy
add action=encrypt comment="" disabled=no dst-address=173.X.X.X/32 dst-port=any \
    ipsec-protocols=esp level=require priority=0 proposal=ipsec protocol=all \
    sa-dst-address=173.X.X.X sa-src-address=50.X.X.X \
    src-address=50.X.X.X/32:any tunnel=yes
/ip ipsec proposal
set default auth-algorithms=md5 comment="" disabled=no enc-algorithms=3des \
    lifetime=60m name=ipsec pfs-group=none
```

What to do next? How to configure such that my devices can initiate connection to the host and for the host to initiate connection to just one particular server? Would it be ip firewall nat, masquerade or ip route?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Describe clearly what You mean by "Any device within my private LAN should be able to initiate connection to the destination host. However, if the destination host wants to connect to my network (directed to my public IP address), I want to forward that connection to just one particular server - 192.168.1.65."?

Answer (score 0):

1. Try ping ip address in ipip tunnel on asa from mikrotik. If IPSec get up and ipip work it success.
2. Build routing inside VPN. On both sides Mikrotik and ASA.
3. Make desired firewall rules to filter traffic inside vpn, if You want this.

You don't need any NAT to connect inside VPN.